# how can I fix a rig/bones whose appearance changed

Tags: rigging, bones, color, rigify

[image]

honestly, I would not know what I did but now I cannot see the pose mode as it was before with colored lines, which concerns me. did I ruin my bones? and if so...how? I was practicing with the shader editor... and with UV... please help I want to understand why they look this way and how I can turn them back to their regular appearance with different line colors and without these big green arrows that are also connected weirdly

please help D:

Comment: That's how bones look in Pose mode, but maybe you've disabled the controllers layer, take a look into the Data panel > Bone Collections and see if you need to enable the visibility of some bones?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. where can I enable the controllers layer? in pose mode I don't see such option..and in bone groups which is the only one similar to "bone collections" I cannot enable anything,,, below I've in the viewport displays octahedral... and group colors but nothing

Comment: Could you please share your file? (remove the mesh if you don't want to share it)

Comment: I can share the files here?

Comment: read the instructions here: https://blend-exchange.com/ or use another platform like workupload

Comment: I think I uploaded the file... I dunno if it worked but It seems...

Comment: you need to copy paste the link  ;)

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=2GE6M2Jr" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/2GE6M2Jr/)   sorry did not know... thought that it was to appear in the post as an attachment

Comment: So in order to be able to move the controller bones you need to switch to Pose Position and the bone collection that is visible seems to be the one with all the controllers, I'm not familiar enough with Rigify to understand why some don't work, maybe precise your question more https://zupimages.net/up/23/49/m1a9.jpg

Comment: well my question was why it changed to that form. when I first created the rig with rigify it came as all the videos and images one can find about rigging with rigify... with an appearance of simple thin lanes with different colors  as an example (https://i.stack.imgur.com/j05Vs.png) it has yellow lines in the head and some green ones and red.... saddly I don't know how else to explain myself